# How to access mail from gmail

Tags: php, cakephp, imap, gmail-imap

I was using imap functions in my app to access gmail. Unforunately I have not been able to use imap any more. I am using php. Is there any alternative way like (api..) to access gmail.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: `Unforunately I have not been able to use imap any more.` _Why not?_

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. [The only GMail API which provides access to mail is the IMAP one.](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't explain why you can't use imap any more, but that's ok.

You can use php [imap extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php) to connect with pop3!

Here is an [example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php#96414).

Answer (score 0):

Try Zend Framework:
Code is Here 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.read.html